# Integral equation in polar coodinate system

Tags: functional-equations, polar-coordinates, integral-equations, inverse-problems

I need an inversion formula with the form $f(r)=\cdots$, from this integral relation:
$$g(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\,f\left(\sqrt{r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0\cos\theta}\right)$$
where $r_0\geq0$ is a constant, $f(r)$ is a unknown real function defined on $r\geq 0$,
and $g(r)$ is a given real function on $-\infty<r<\infty$.

This equation derived from [a polar coordinate system like this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yy9x803siwpzq1b/image.png?dl=0).

By changing of the variable:
$u:=\sqrt{r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0\cos\theta}$ , I got a formula such as
$$
g(r)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{|r-r_0|}^{|r+r_0|}du\,\frac{2uf(u)}{\sqrt{((r+r_0)^2-u^2)(u^2-(r-r_0)^2)}}.
$$

I expect the inversion can be solved since this relation looks somewhat like the [Abel transform formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_transform), but it is not succesful yet.

Can someone help this transform?

If needed, $f$ and $g$ can be assumed as $(f,g<\infty),\ (f,g>0)$, differentiable, or converging fast enough when $r\rightarrow\infty$.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my halting English.